# Angular Hybrid : error with LoadChildren and upgraded component

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-router, angular-hybrid

I'm trying to create an Hybrid App (Angular + AngularJS) with lazy loaded Angular modules.

When I try to lazy load a module with a component that hold an upgraded AngularJS component I have the following error :

**Route**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'toto',
    loadChildren: () => import('./toto/toto.module').then(module => module.TotoModule)
  }
];
```

**Error**

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Trying to get the AngularJS injector before it being set.
Error: Trying to get the AngularJS injector before it being set.
    at injectorFactory (upgrade-static.umd.js:1266)
    at _callFactory (ng_module.ts:201)
    at _createProviderInstance (ng_module.ts:154)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (ng_module.ts:110)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (refs.ts:423)
    at Object.resolveDep (provider.ts:424)
    at Injector_.get (refs.ts:372)
    at new UpgradeHelper (upgrade-static.umd.js:1491)
    at new UpgradeComponent (upgrade-static.umd.js:1802)
    at new MyExampleDirective (VM270 toto.module.ts:13)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1255)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1209)
    at eval (zone.js:1321)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:434)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.ts:390)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:433)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:205)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:620)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:520)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1656)
```

When I import the module inside the AppModule and do the following routes it works fine :

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'toto',
    children: TotoRoutes
  }
];
```

I have created 2 stackblitz :

- The one using lazy loading, triggering the error :
  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uye3ld
- The one without lazy loading :
  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3aogfs

Comment: That is not the correct syntax for loadChildren..?

Comment: The question have been updated with the good syntax. I'm still having the error when I try to lazy load the module.